# Merge rows if value from two files match - Python

Tags: python, merge

I have two files, file1 looks like this:

```
#query_name KEGG_KOs
PROKKA_00019   K00240
PROKKA_00020   K00246
PROKKA_00022   K02887
```

file2:

```
Geneid  Chr Count
PROKKA_00019    k141_1000050    102
PROKKA_00020    k141_1000050    132
PROKKA_00021    k141_1000054    36
```

If '#query_name' from file1 matches 'Geneid' from file2 then to create file3 which looks like this:

```
Geneid  KEGG_KOs    Chr Count
PROKKA_00019    K00240  k141_1000050    102
PROKKA_00020    K00246  k141_1000050    132
```

I haven't been able to create file3, so far I've written the following but haven't been able to get it to work. Other options could be using [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) but I can tell all I need is a simple script. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
filenames =['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
with open('file3.txt', 'w') as collated:
    with open('1.txt', 'r') as genes:
        with open('2.txt', 'r') as counts:
            if '#query_name' in genes == 'Geneid' in counts:
                for line1, line2 in zip(genes, counts):
                    print(line1.strip(), line2.strip(), file=collated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using pandas:

Input:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep='\t')
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='#query_name' , right_on='Geneid' , how='inner').drop(['#query_name'],axis=1)
merged_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Output of merged_df :

```
  KEGG_KOs        Geneid           Chr  Count
0   K00240  PROKKA_00019  k141_1000050    102
1   K00246  PROKKA_00020  k141_1000050    132
```

Line 2 and 3 are just reading in the txt files (I assume they are tab delimited) and saving them as pandas dataframes (df1 and df2). On line 4, I merge df1 and df2 using the #query_name and Geneid columns and then drop the #query_name column. I save the output as a csv, and the index (0, 1) is dropped. If you want to save the merged dataframe as a tab delimited file, you only need to change the last line to: `merged_df.to_csv('output.txt', sep='\t', index=False)`

---

If you are getting a keyerror, it must mean your files' formatting might be a bit wonky (there is a mix of spaces and tabs). This code should work:

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
def to_df(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        df = [line.strip().split() for line in f]
    return pd.DataFrame(df[1:], columns=df[0])
df1 = to_df('file1.txt')
df2 = to_df('file2.txt')
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='#query_name' , right_on='Geneid' , how='inner').drop(['#query_name'],axis=1)
merged_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
  KEGG_KOs        Geneid           Chr Count
0   K00240  PROKKA_00019  k141_1000050   102
1   K00246  PROKKA_00020  k141_1000050   132
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you for your response. I get a 'KeyError' message to your script.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*******", line 5, in <module>
    merged = genes.merge(counts, left_on='#query_name' , right_on='Geneid' , how='inner').drop(['#query_name'],axis=1)
 ....
  File "*******", line 1382, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '#query_name'

Comment: Your files look like they have a mix of spaces and tabs, so the original code was group some of your column names together. I have added another code to the answer that should correct that issue.